# Probability that the maximal number of bags has at least one ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Assume that there are $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls for a total of $t = b+w$. Also, there are $k$ bags each with capacity of exactly $c$ balls s.t. $t=kc$ and we want to assign all $t$ balls to bags of equal size.

My goal is to ensure that the maximal number of bags has at least one black ball each. The assignment is random hence I need to compute the probability that exactly $\operatorname{min}\{k,b\}$ bags have at least one black ball each.

If $b \leq k$, then I think that the answer lies in picking the $b$ bags to contain one black ball each. We multiply this by the number of assignments of black and white balls to the bags and then divide by the total number of assignments:

$$\frac{{{k}\choose b} \binom{b}{1,\cdots,1}\binom{w}{c-1,\cdots,c-1,w-b(c-1)}}{\binom{t}{c,\cdots,c}}$$

where in the numerator

- first multinomial has $b$ terms equal to $1$ (one black ball per bag until we don't have any more black balls).
- second multinomial has $b$ terms equal to $c-1$ (to fill the partially-black bags with white balls) and one term equal to $w-b(c-1)$ (arbitrarily assign the remaining white balls).

and the denominator has $k$ terms equal to $c$ (all possible ball assignments).

Is this correct? Also, I cannot figure out the case of $b>k$.

Comment: Are you sure that the balls are distinguishable? From the description it does not seem, but in your procedure you pick the balls.

Comment: The distinction is between black and white (based on my assumptions), no other distinction is assumed. What is your point?

Comment: that you are assuming that you can distinguish in between $2$ black balls cause you are doing $\binom{b}{1,\cdots ,1}.$

Comment: Oh, got it. I have just fixed this mistake.

Comment: I do not think this is right if you agree that the balls should be indistinguishable(see that you are choosing the whites too). You should aim for computing something like in how many ways can you put the blacks and so the denominator is $|\{a_1+a_2+\cdots a_k=b\}|$ where i mean you have $a_1$ black balls in the first bag. etc. Have you seen stars and bars? Try to use it. Now, if you have no idea of what i am talking about and you have just seen multinomials and think then that the balls are distinguishable, your computation was fine. Let me know if you want me to go further.

Comment: I believe that for the sake of computing the probability we can safely assume that the balls and the bags are distinguishable as one way to count the possible assignments. I have reverted the change. I have heard of stars and bars but I am not sure how it applies here. I believe that there are multiple ways to solve it so if you can elaborate on your idea it would help.